# Attempt - A rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus

I have another rebus puzzle for you guys to solve :D ; It's on the easier side

Here it goes,

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems too obvious:

> A Bold Attempt

Comment: Correct! i thought so too but i still posted it :P :/

I'm gonna come up with a harder one